# Unexpected set_value

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Im trying to repopulate my form but this error is shown

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'set_value' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\groupie\application\views\register.php on line 31
```

Here is my code

```
echo '<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError">School ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSchoolID" id="inputError" value="'set_value('inputSchoolID')';">
    <span class="help-block">'. form_error('inputSchoolID') .'</span>
</div>';
```

This is the part where it errors

**value="'set_value('inputSchoolID')';"**

Comment: You need to learn how to format code and make use of the correct " and ' and perhaps make use of \" and \'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing dots, change it like in your `form_error`:

```
echo '<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError">School ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSchoolID" id="inputError" value="' . set_value('inputSchoolID') . ';">
    <span class="help-block">'. form_error('inputSchoolID') .'</span>
</div>';
```

Comment: Yeah just noticed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake I forgot to put periods. It should be

value = " ' . set_value('inputSchoolID') . '; "

Answer (score 0):

You missed the concatenation dots (.)

```
echo '<div class="form-group has-error">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputError">School ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSchoolID" id="inputError" value="'.set_value('inputSchoolID').';">
                        <span class="help-block">'. form_error('inputSchoolID') .'</span>
                        </div>';
```